# Bind Bool to Visibility of TextBlock within a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I want to bind `visibility` of a `textblock`, within a `listbox`, to a `bool` value in my `ViewModel`. Binding works well to a `textblock` outside the `listbox`, but it isn't working to the `textblock` within the `listbox`. Please help!

xaml code:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="heading" Visibility="{Binding MyVb.Visible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" Width="480"/>
<ListBox x:Name="lstBani1" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tb1" Text="{Binding string1}" Visibility="{Binding MyVb.Visible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" Width="480"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tb2" Text="{Binding string2}"  Width="480"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tb3" Text="{Binding string3}" Width="480"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

cs code:

```
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
        model.Users = GetUsers();
        model.MyVb = new MyVisibility();
        model.MyVb.Visible = false;
        this.DataContext = model;
    }
    // View Model
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
        public MyVisibility MyVb { get; set; }
    }

     // Bool to Visibility Converter
     public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    // Property Classes
    public class User
    {
        public string string1 { get; set; }
        public string string2 { get; set; }
        public string string3 { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyVisibility : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _Visible;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public bool Visible
        {
            get { return _Visible; }
            set
            {
                _Visible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Visible");
            }
        }
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
    private List<Bani> GetUsers() {....}                    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ListBox` is bound to `Users`, therefore each item in the list is has a `DataContext` bound to a `User`. Therefore your binding is trying to look for the property in the `User` class, not the parent data context.

Give your page a `Name` and change your binding to the following:

```
Visibility="{Binding DataContext.MyVb.Visible, ElementName=yourPageName, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
```

Comment: I added this`<phone:PhoneApplicationPage .......    **Title="MyPage**" >` and changed my binding to `Visibility="{Binding DataContext.MyVb.Visible, ElementName=MyPage, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"` , but now whether the `bool` is `true` or `false`, the `text` within the first `textblock` is not appearing, though white space appears in that place. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It should be: `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage Name="MyPage" ...`

Comment: My mistake! Thanks for such a quick response, it worked :)